# How Kibana Virtualization filter based on min @timestamp

Tags: kibana

So I want to use Kibana visualization using Kibana UI. And what I want to do is to filter "Min Time" that I already have aggregate using Min. For Example, Min Time > 2021-11-20. How do I do that in this dashboard? or is that any way that I query manually? Here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

And in advance tab, apparently, I can add JSON Script, how can I use that?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use the time picker in the top right to do this?

Comment: because for example, I need the data where I should know this user only using this function this week from the past 6 months. In order to do it, the time picker on the top right should be 6 months ago and I filter whoever user has Min Time around now to 1 week ago.